# How to sequentially load and display different lists, using Angular RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to make multiple http requests in a specified order. Upon receiving a response, the data should be displayed as a list in the view. After all responses are received, the view consists of multiple lists, one per request.

```
const req = [
  this.domainService.getDomain(filterNG).pipe(map(resp => resp.data), finalize(() => this.loadingNG = false)),
  this.domainService.getDomain(filterCodAML).pipe(map(resp => resp.data), finalize(() => this.loadingCodAML = false)),
  this.domainService.getDomain(filterTipoRating).pipe(map(resp => {
    resp.data.unshift({code: this.TIPO_RATING_ALL, description: this.translate.instant('tutti')});
    return resp.data;
  }), finalize(() => this.loadingTipiRating = false)),
  this.komodoService.listProvince$().pipe(finalize(() => this.loadingProvince = false)),
  this.domainService.getDomain(filterGRA).pipe(map(resp => resp.data), finalize(() => this.loadingGRA = false)),
  this.anagraficaService.getListaFiliali({filter: {all: false}})
    .pipe(map(resp => resp.data), finalize(() => this.loadingFiliali = false))

]
```

I use **concatMap** to make the http requests in a predefined order:

```
from(req).pipe(
  concatMap((request) => request.pipe()),
).subscribe(resp => { console.log(resp)})
```

My issue and objective is to push each **resp** to a separate list, as the different HTTP services return data that needs to be displayed in separate HTML lists.

I don't know how to save each returned response in a way that I can assign it to the appropriate list. Currently the pipe emits individual result objects instead of an array of result objects.

Comment: Please check my (late) answer. I created a fully working example with Angular 15, including a stackblitz-demo.

Answer (score 1):

I created a complete working example with an array of observables that get loaded sequentially while the view is updated everytime an observable has resolved.

**[Click here for my stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wu8aze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,tsconfig.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Or check my code-snippets below:

**Interfaces:**

```
interface Sources {
  [key: string]: Observable<any>;
}

interface KeyValuePair {
  key: string;
  result: any;
}
```

**Component.ts:**

I use the `scan`-operator to add each new emission to an array that already contains the previous emissions:

```
listWrappers$: Observable<KeyValuePair[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  const sources$: Sources = {
    list1: of([10000, 2999]),
    list2: of(['Patrick', 'Paul']),
  };

  this.listWrappers$ = of(...Object.entries(sources$)).pipe(
    concatMap(([key, obs$]) => obs$.pipe(map((result) => ({ key, result })))),
    scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr] as KeyValuePair[], [] as KeyValuePair[]
    )
  );
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="listWrappers$ | async as keyValuePairs">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let pair of keyValuePairs">

    <ng-container *ngIf="pair.key === 'list1'">
      <b>List 1</b>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of pair.result">
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="pair.key === 'list2'">
      <b>List 2</b>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of pair.result">
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>

  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forkJoin`

```
forkJoin(req).subscribe(arrayOfResponss=>doSomethingWithIt)
```

Comment: but forkJoin doesn't return sequentially

Comment: forkJoin emits in the same order you supplied the observables

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object with all requests and use different keys that you'll pass to your `subscribe()` handler to distinguish where it came from:

```
import { of, map, concatMap, from } from 'rxjs';

const sources = {
  key1: of(123),
  key2: of('abc'),
};

from(Object.entries(sources))
  .pipe(
    concatMap(([key, obs$]) => obs$.pipe(
      map(result => ({ key, result })),
    ))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lgagzk?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: I got an error on map operator: TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: Stackblitz doesn't show any error so make sure you're importing the right `map()`